# SAS Semicolon In MAcro variable

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a macro variable which contains a string to later execute in a data step. The issue I am having is that I need the macro variable to contain semi-colons. The following doesn't work. How can I add a semi colon to this variable declaration?

```
    %let commandString='';

    data _null_;
    set DATA;

    if decile =1 then call symput('commandString', cat(&commandString, " if p_adj >", min, " then decile_ =1" , %str(;) ) ) ;

    run;

%put &commandString
```

**ADD:**

This is what I would like to have happen. I'd like the result to be

```
First Part; Second Part;
```

But it does not work.

```
%let commandString=%nrstr('First Part';);

data _null_;
call symput('commandString',cat(&commandString,%nrstr('Second Part';)) ;
run;

%put &commandString;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do overall?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to create a macro variable which has if then rules for binning a numeric variable. For example: " if p_adj >= 0.025 and p<0.05 then decile_ =1;"

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but this generally isn't a good way to do recoding/binning. If you provide more details, perhaps there's an easier solution. If you'd like to stick with this method, I'm sure someone else will have an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not provided the reproducable code so, I have modified it a little bit to test the functioning.

Since you want to assign semicolon(;) to the macro variable you are basically asking SAS to treat it differently for that you would have to use one of the **masking functions called - `%nrstr`** which - Masks special characters, including & and %, and mnemonic operators in constant text during macro compilation

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000208352.htm

```
%let commandString=%nrstr('';);
data _null_;
%put &commandString ;
run;
```

**EDIT**(as question has been edited)

1. The position of single quotes is wrong in your code, singles quotes should include semicolon as well because you want to include them as well.
2. In the call symput part you are missing a bracket.

**Revised code**

```
 %let commandString=%nrstr('First Part;');
    data _null_;
    call symput('commandString',cat(&commandString,%nrstr('Second Part;')));
    run;
    %put "&commandString";
    %put %nrquote(&commandString);
```

Since the commandstring resolves to the value which contains semicolons (;) so in order to print it's value using the %put function you would have to mask it as well, otherwise it would throw an error. Here you could use "" to treat it as string or you would have to use **`%nrquote` to mask the semicolon at the time of resolving**

- %nrquote - Masks special characters, including & and %, and mnemonic
  operators in a resolved value at macro execution.
- http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000208412.htm

---

Comment: Does this allow concatenating a ';' to the end of the macro variable string?

Comment: I have added to the question.

Comment: Thanks. When you do %put &commandString; without the double quotes - it doesnt work. Any idea how to correct? I think I need to eliminate the quotes else I cant execute the string in a data step: Data A; Set B; &commandString; run;

Comment: You only need to use `%str()` and `%quote()`, using the 'nr' versions of these is overkill unless you have a string containing an & or % symbols.  I believe linking the descriptions to these functions would be clearer than linking the 'nr' descriptions.